# google sheets COUNTIF range contains a string (defined using cell referencing)

Tags: excel, google-sheets, countif

I have text defined in column A, and in column B I want to search another sheet for cells containing these strings. I have tried the `COUNTIF` function, which can be used to count cells containing the exact text, but not for cells which include the defined string:

```
A         B        
red
green
blue
```

If in column B I use `=COUNTIF(sheet2!F1:F10,A1)`, I can count cells which contain 'red' exactly, but not cells which may include 'red' amongst other text.

I know you can use `=COUNTIF(sheet2!F1:F10,"\*red\*")` when the string is already defined, is there a way to to this when the string is referenced from another cell?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, concatenate the string with the variable:

```
=COUNTIF(sheet2!F1:F10,"*" & A1 & "*")
```